# I am creating a django review system. I think my Html is wrong

Tags: html, django, web

I created the form and added it to view, how I must add it to html form?

index.html

```
        <form action="." method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add comment"></p>
</form>
      <h1 style="margin:0 57%">Reviews</h1>
    <input type="hidden" name="parent" id="contactparent" value="">
    <div class="dfv" style="display:flex; padding: 5%;   justify-content: space-around;  flex-wrap: wrap;align-items:center; box-shadow:4px 4px 16px gold;width: 80%;margin:8% 18% 0">
    <div class="form-group editContent">
     <label for="contactcomment" class="editContent"  placeholder=" Message" >
      Your reviews *
     </label>
```

views.py

```
class AddReview(View):
"""Отзывы"""
def post(self, request,pk):
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST,)
    if form.is_valid():
        form = form.save(commit=False)
        #form.Dish = Dish
        form.save()
    review = Reviews.objects.all()
    return render(request,'index.html',{'Reviews':review})
```

forms.py

```
class ReviewForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model =  Reviews
    fields = ('name', 'email', 'text')
```

urls.py
`path("review/<int:pk>/", AddReview.as_view(), name='add_review'),`
Request not found. Request URL: [http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7Burl%20'add_review'%20dish.id%7D](http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7Burl%20%27add_review%27%20dish.id%7D)

Comment: You can share views.py and forms.py in the question by clicking on edit button there instead of pasting them in comments which is not clear.

Comment: "Didn't work" is not a great problem description. Please explain what you expect and what actually happens. Errors in console and network tab, server log?

Comment: Try adding the form to the context, `{'form': form, 'Dish': dish, 'Snack': snack, 'Desserts': desserts, 'Lastcourses': lastcourses, 'Reviews': reviews}` so that it will show up in `{{ form.as_p }}`.

Comment: When I'm trying to add comment it gives:
Method Not Allowed (POST): /

Comment: You're trying to handle a post request using get.  You need to have a `def post` as well as a `def get` in your `DishView`.  Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the original question as to how to add the form to your HTML is to put the form into the context that is sent to the template:

`{'form': form, 'Dish': dish, 'Snack': snack, 'Desserts': desserts, 'Lastcourses': lastcourses, 'Reviews': reviews}`

Now for the rest.  Here's what I had before you made all the changes to your code.  The problem, I think is you're mixing function based views with class based views together in the same view.  Second, you are handling either get *or* post when you need to handle both in the same view.

```py
class DishView(View):
    form_class = ReviewForm
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.name = request.name
            form.text = request.text
            form.save()
            return redirect(self.path)

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

I also think you have an error in your form tag.  If you want the form to be submitted back to the same view, then you don't use `"."`.  You can leave the action out:

```html
<form method="post">
<!-- OR -->
<form action="" method="post">
```